# how to find neighbors for cell in akari by prolog

Tags: prolog

I try to solve akari/light-up game in prolog .
Firstly I want to find the four cells around a cell by neighbors() but it gives one cell only ... After that I want to find all cells in y with this cell by yneighbors() .... Anything as help will be useful .....
my code :

```
size(8,8).

wall(1,6).
wall(2,2).
wall(2,3).
wall(3,7).
wall(4,1).
wall(4,5).
wall(5,4).
wall(5,8).
wall(6,2).
wall(7,6).
wall(7,7).
wall(8,3).

wallnum(1,6,1).
wallnum(2,2,3).
wallnum(3,7,0).
wallnum(5,4,4).
wallnum(5,8,0).
wallnum(6,2,2).
wallnum(7,6,1).

light(1,2).
light(1,7).
light(2,1).
light(2,8).
light(3,2).
light(4,4).
light(4,6).
light(5,3).
light(5,5).
light(6,1).
light(6,4).
light(7,2).
light(7,8).
light(8,6).

cell(X,Y):-X>0,X<9,Y>0,Y<9.

neighbors(X,Y,L):-cell(X,Y),
cell(X+1,Y),X1 is X + 1,Y1 is Y  ,L =[X1,Y1];
cell(X-1,Y),X1 is X - 1,Y1 is Y  ,L=[X1,Y1];
cell(X,Y+1),X1 is X    ,Y1 is Y + 1 ,L=[X1,Y1];
cell(X,Y-1),X1 is X    ,Y1 is Y - 1 ,L=[X1,Y1].

yneighbors(X,Y,L):-cell(X,Y+1),L=[X,Y].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
neighbor(X,Y,NX,Y):-
    NX is X-1,
    cell(NX,Y).

neighbor(X,Y,NX,Y):-
    NX is X+1,
    cell(NX,Y).

neighbor(X,Y,X,NY) :-
    NY is Y-1,
    cell(X,NY).

neighbor(X,Y,X,NY) :-
    NY is Y+1,
    cell(X,NY).

neighbors(X,Y,L) :-
    findall(neighbor(NX,NY),neighbor(X,Y,NX,NY),L).
```

Explanation:

predicate calls like `cell(X+1,Y)` are ill-formed. That is equivalent to `cell(+(X,1),Y)`. You should notice that X+1 is just a term, not a mathematical expression. So, it is not evaluated.

Mathematical expressions are evaluated by means of is/2.

You should review your Prolog knowledge since most code has no sense.

```
yneighbors(X,Y,L):-cell(X,Y+1),L=[X,Y].
```

will always fail.

If you persist in predicate calls like `cell(X+Y,Z)`, you should evaluate arguments to cell/2:

```
cell(X,Y) :-
   EvalX is X,
   EvalY is Y,
   EvalY > 0, 
   ...
```

But, I also discourage such a practice.